# Sass image url reference error, chained imports

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, sass-loader

> - src
>
>   - images/image1.jpg
>   - sass/sass1.scss (background-image: url('../images/image1.jpg'))
>   - folder1/folder2/sass2.scss (@import '../../sass/sass1')

This is my folder structure. When I try to import sass1 into sass2, the image's path is not resolved as the sass loader expects the image path to be relative to the final file ,i.e, sass2 in our case.

Path where the sass loader searches the image is - 'folder1/images/image1.jpg' and not 'src/images/image1.jpg'.

I am using webpack(v1) for bundling.

Comment: Images should be put in an 'assets' folder in the public folder... aka 'public/assets'. This means that if your styles are compiled, the URL will be relative to the URL path than the project folder.

Comment: You also need to provide the bundled folder path.

Comment: The image is loaded in the public folder. But the sass loader is not able to resolve the path that is the issue.

Comment: doesnt 'sass/sass1.scss (background-image: url('images/image1.jpg'))' make it ?

Comment: sass/sass1.scss does make it.
But when i am trying to import sass1 into sass2, sass2 searches the image relative to its own path.

Comment: Like even if you did "./images/image1.jpg" would also resolve this... and according to your project directory, the image is in src/

Comment: Because the public folder is created by webpack's dev server and serves  the file on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

**edit** this answer should also account for webpack using src/image1 or wherever the images are before the bundle.
You need to make sure the final css path for an image is relative to the css filepath on the server. (See final section below)

Given the folder directory

```
src/
  sass/
    sass1.scss
    sass2.scss
public/
  images/
    image1.png
```

**scss2**

```
@import "scss1"
```

**scss1**

```
.class {
  background: url("./images/image1.png")
 }
```

If the output scss1.css is compiled into css and placed in public, such that the public folder now looks like

```
src/
  sass/
    sass1.scss
    sass2.scss
public/
  images/
    image1.png
index.html
scss1.css
```

Comment: Upvoting because it would work in general but my case is something different. Have followed a new approach.
@DenisTsoi Thanks for the help.